# Re-play/Repeat/Re-Fire Azure BlobStorage Function Triggers for existing files

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-triggers

I've just uploaded several 10s of GBs of files to Azure CloudStorage.
Each file should get picked up and processed by a FunctionApp, in response to a `BlobTrigger`:

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(ImportDataFile))]
public async Task ImportDataFile(
    // Raw JSON Text file containing data updates in expected schema
    [BlobTrigger("%AzureStorage:DataFileBlobContainer%/{fileName}", Connection = "AzureStorage:ConnectionString")]
    Stream blobStream,
    string fileName)
{
    //...
}
```

This works in general, but foolishly, I did not do a final test of that Function prior to uploading all the files to our UAT system ... and there was a problem with the uploads :(

The upload took a few days (running over my Domestic internet uplink due to CoViD-19) so I really don't want to have to re-do that.

**Is there some way to "replay" the BlobUpload Triggers?** so that the function triggers again as if I'd just re-uploaded the files ... without having to transfer any data again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a hacky-AF work around, that re-processes the existing file:

If you add Metadata to a blob, that appears to re-trigger the BlobStorage Function Trigger.

Accessed in Azure Storage Explorer, but Right-clicking on a Blob > Properties > Add Metadata.

I was settings Key: "ForceRefresh", Value "test".

Answer (score 6):

As per this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#blob-receipts)

> Azure Functions stores blob receipts in a container named
>   `azure-webjobs-hosts` in the Azure storage account for your function app
>   (defined by the app setting `AzureWebJobsStorage`).
>
> **To force reprocessing of a blob, delete the blob receipt for that blob
>   from the azure-webjobs-hosts container manually**. While reprocessing
>   might not occur immediately, it's guaranteed to occur at a later point
>   in time. **To reprocess immediately, the scaninfo blob in
>   azure-webjobs-hosts/blobscaninfo can be updated. Any blobs with a last
>   modified timestamp after the LatestScan property will be scanned
>   again**.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Skimmed through that page, but didn't spot that section!

Comment: Can you give it a try though? I haven’t tried it myself.

Comment: Have now tried it. Doesn't appear to actually work, which is very dissappointing :( Still a useful answer to have on SO, since it's highlighting the docs that say how it *SHOULD* work.

Comment: `Might be worth editting a "See Comments", though?` - I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Oh, you mean edit the answer and include a reference to your comment that it doesn't actually work?

Comment: Oh, you mean edit the answer and include a reference to your comment that it doesn't actually work?

Comment: You may also want to check for related blobs in the poison queue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#poison-blobs

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the processing of blobs in my code which meant that there were a bunch of messages in the `webjobs-blobtrigger-poison` queue.  I had to move them back to azure-`webjobs-blobtrigger-name-of-function-app`.  Removing the blob receipts and adjusting the `scaninfo` blob did not work without the above step.

Fortunately Azure Storage Explorer has a menu option to move the messages from one queue to another:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, if you aren't invested in the file name:

Azure Storage Explorer, has a "Clone with new name" button in the top bar, which will add a new file (and trigger the Function) without transferring the data via your local machine.

*Note that "Copy" followed by "Paste" also re-triggers the blob, but appears to transfer the data down to your machine and then back up again ... **incredibly** slowly!*

Comment: Note that doing this doesn't appear to change the `LastModifiedStamp` so who knows how it will interact with ScanInfo

Answer (score 0):

The other answers either do not work for me, or are too expensive of an operation to be feasible. I had to do this for 100k+ blobs due to an outage, here is the app that I wrote to manage this functionality. Requires two packages:
`<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.0" />`
`<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Async" Version="6.0.1" />`

```
public class Program
{
    private static string _blobStorageConnectionString = "YOURCONNECTIONSTRING";
    private static DateTime _filterAfterDate = new DateTime(2023, 10, 17);

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_blobStorageConnectionString);
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("YOUR_CONTAINER_HERE");
        long iterator = 0;
        await foreach (var blob in blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.Metadata).Where(x => x.Properties.LastModified > _filterAfterDate/*OR ANY OTHER FILTERS*/))
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            blobClient.SetMetadata(blob.Metadata.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value));

            Console.WriteLine($"{++iterator} : Resubmitted blob {blob.Name}\nLastModifiedDate {blob.Properties.LastModified}\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This does not actually require any downloading or resetting of any blobs, and maintains metadata